# did request.POST['choice'] returns an Integer

Tags: django, django-orm

I am  learning django can you please help me with this

```
selected_choice=question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])

selected_choice.votes+=1
```

Here, the selected_choice is holding a particular choice object but what is the functionality of `request.POST['choice]` I'm confused with this

Comment: `choice` can be anything it depends on what your form send

Comment: so it is like what is have stated in the template right? 
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">

Comment: Data accessed via request.POST will always be strings. You should use Django forms to handle validation and conversion, it will convert data to an integer if you use a forms.IntegerField

Comment: I didnt used any form in the application just templates 
so it is like what is have stated in the template right? 
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">----can you explain whats hapening here ....
*forloop.counter indicates how many times the for tag has gone through its loop            [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're submitting your form with through post method, you will be able to access all data that you're submitting in the form using `request.POST` (This is a dictionary in python).
Since `<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">` has `name="choice"` the dictionary has a key named choice which holds the value of the choice id (because you've set `value="{{ choice.id }}`)

So request.POST['choice'] gives you the id of the choice. `pk` stands for primary key. So `get(pk=request.POST['choice'])` gives you the choice object which has it's pk (which is the id by default) equal to the choice id you got back from the form.